# siunitx carry error when rounding? \num{89.80} renders as 810

Tags: siunitx

I've found what I'm afraid is either a bug or a supremely foolish error on my part: whenever I ask siunitx to render `\num{89.80}`, rounding by figures, it renders it as "810.".  Likewise, `\num{898.0}` comes out as "8100.".  After a bit of poking around, it appears that this happens whenever rounding a number with more than two digits in such a way that the largest place changes (see other examples below), as if the "9" in "89" is rounded to "10" and then the "8" is incremented to "9" and these are just concatenated.  I've included a minimal example below.  I'm running pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) and the version of siunitx included in that TeXLive distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{round-mode=figures}    
\begin{document}

% these all render very strangely
\num{89.80}                      % 810.
\num[round-precision=3]{89.99}   % 810.0
\num{898.0}                      % 8100.
\num{19.8}                       % 110.
\num{99.8}                       % 910.
\num{9999}                       % 91 000

% these are totally fine
\num{9.98}
\num[round-mode=off]{89.80}
\num[round-mode=places]{89.80}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for supplying a complete MWE :) I'm not 100% sure the `{texlive}` tag is appropriate here, unless you're sure that it *only* happens with this distribution and not others (e.g MiKTeX). Is there a reason you can't use a more up to date version of TeXlive? Welcome!

Comment: You are very vague on version of `siunitx`: add `\listfiles` to your input and find the version from the resulting `*File list*` in your `.log` file. For me with the current release (2.5q) all is fine.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph: the `siunitx` version is v2.0n.  I did try to update using `tlmgr` but it looks like I'll have to update my whole distribution.

Comment: @DaveKleinschmidt No, not your whole set up, just part of it :-) Give me a few minutes to write something helpful!

Comment: @DaveKleinschmidt And is there any reason why _not to_ upgrade the whole distibution? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 2.0n is quite old now: released 2010-07-15 according to the change log. There have been a lot of bug fixes since then, and pinning down just the 'appropriate fix' looks a little tedious. I would therefore suggest updating your `siunitx` installation to the current release. This will also require updated versions of the LaTeX3 support. You need the following from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/):

- [`siunitx.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx.tds.zip)
- [`l3kernel.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip)
- [`l3packages.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip)

These then need to be installed in your local tree: by far the easiest way is to unzip them into `~/texmf` (assuming you are on Unix).

Comment: No problem now.  Thanks a lot for the quick response and the great package!